# Use of RSA in Yaksha Security System

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, rsa

So I'm reading over the Yaksha Security System and see it is based on the RSA cryptosystem and a centralized server, easy enough. What I'm slightly confused on is the math behind the related keys.

It states

```
nAlice - Alice(some user) modulus
dAliceA - First private key only known to Alice
dAliceY - Second Private key only known to Yaksha server
eAlice - Alice's public key
```

The keys are related by the following:

```
dAliceA*dAliceY mod phi(mod nAlice) = dAlice
```

It states that the server sends Alice:

```
Calice = (Ksession) ^ dAliceY*eAlice mod nAlice
```

And Alice can determine the session key as:

```
(Calice)^dAliceA mod nAlice = Ksession
```

My question is, Can Alice obtain the session key due to the multiplicative properties of the modulus function and the basis of which RSA is built on? Or am I missing something here?

Edit: Also, is dAlice just the combined private key of the server and Alice to verify that the keys are correct?

Comment: This question might get more attention at http://crypto.stackexchange.com